# What is the significance of the word "Correctness" in Software Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, terminology

There is a fact in Software Testing which says :

**Testing is used to find errors in the Software but cannot be used to show the correctness of Software .** 
I am unable to get the significance of the Word Correctness here .
Also is it true that Correctness is impossible to achieve in a Software ?

Comment: The same way you cannot prove something to be "true", you can only (repeatedly) fail to prove it false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since sufficiently complex software may have an infinite number of possible bugs, it is logically impossible to show the correctness of software by testing.

Absence of ***revealed errors*** (bugs) doesn't imply absence of ***all errors***.

Comment: Can we say that Correctness is possible if it is able to meet out its utility for which it is designed . If all the requirement is met out for which the software is designed and if we are able to debug all the errors then it is a correct software for us .

Comment: Yes, but the testing can not show that your software is mathematically correct, or 100% correct, or that it will *always* return the desired output. You can define when the software has been sufficiently tested depending on your acceptance tests, but strictly speaking, testing cannot show correctness.

Comment: Testing cannot show correctness . Are we saying this because it is not feasible to test it on all inputs . I want to know that we should associate correctness with its capability to meet out the requirements or with its output from all possible inputs .

Comment: Correctness in this context applies to the theoretical impossibility of testing every possible combination. You can define what does it mean for the software to be correct in accordance with acceptance criteria.

Comment: Are the testing tools capable enough to test it on all input combinations ?

Comment: What testing tools exactly? Let me give you an example. If you have a simple calculator that can add positive integers you cannot possibly test all input combinations because there is an infinite number of combinations and you do not have infinite amount of time unless you are God.

Answer (score 0):

> Testing is used to find errors in the Software but cannot be used to
> show the correctness of Software.
>
> What is the significance of the Word Correctness here.

A *unit* of software is [*functionally
correct*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correctness_(computer_science))
if it produces the correct output for every possible input.

In *theoretical computer science*, there are many nuances in this term,
for example, we differentiate between *partial correctness* and *total
correctness*: It is *partial correct* if the answers it returns are
correct, and it is *total correct* if it always returns the correct
answer.

In *practice*, however, things are a bit more complex.  When we are
building large software systems, it is not always easy to formally
define what the correct output of a program is, and then we talk about
*correct according to specifications*.

I don't think the claim *"testing is used to find errors but cannot be
used to show correctness*", is stated in a good way.  The term *software
testing* usually means a small computer program that runs your software
on certain inputs and verify that the output is as expected.  I would
state it as *testing is used to prevent errors from being introduced in
existing code*.

> Is it true that Correctness is impossible to achieve in a Software?

No, it is not impossible.  Try to write the *identity function*, for
example: `f(x) → x`.  It's quite easy, actually.  The more complex
algorithm, the more difficult it is to write it correct.

Not only is it possible to *write correct code*, it is also possible to
[*prove that code is
correct*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification).  However,
this is much more difficult and time consuming.

What you cannot do, though, is to show that code is correct in terms of
testing only (unless your function only takes a finite (small) amount of
inputs).